# MySQL call is returning an incorrectly combined result, or a all null row if tables involved are empty

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation, distinct

So I have these tables in my database with this data:

```
building_officer_membership
+--------------------------------+-------------+------------+
| building_officer_membership_id | building_id | officer_id |
+--------------------------------+-------------+------------+
|                              1 |           1 |          1 |
|                              2 |           1 |          2 |
+--------------------------------+-------------+------------+

building
+-------------+-----------------+
| building_id | name            |
+-------------+-----------------+
|           1 | a_nice_building |
+-------------+-----------------+

officer
+------------+------------+-----------+
| officer_id | first_name | last_name |
+------------+------------+-----------+
|          1 | Brandon    | Thompson  |
|          2 | Mark       | Bobby     |
+------------+------------+-----------+

Manager
+------------+---------------+
| manager_id | full_name     |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 | Bill Lumbergh |
|          2 | Bob Page      |
+------------+---------------+

 officer manager membership
+-------------------------------+------------+------------+
| officer_manager_membership_id | officer_id | manager_id |
+-------------------------------+------------+------------+
|                             1 |          1 |          1 |
|                             2 |          2 |          2 |
+-------------------------------+------------+------------+
```

I have an MySQL call that returns each officer associated with a building (in the building_officer_membership table.)  To make it more informative, I also list in each result the manager(s) that the officers are under.

When I make this SQL call,

```
SELECT building_officer_membership.building_officer_membership_id,
building_officer_membership.building_id,
building_officer_membership.officer_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT manager.full_name) as manager_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT manager.manager_id) AS manager_id
from building_officer_membership
JOIN building on building.building_id = building_officer_membership.building_id
JOIN officer on officer.officer_id = building_officer_membership.officer_id
JOIN officer_manager_membership on officer.officer_id = officer_manager_membership.officer_id
LEFT JOIN manager ON officer_manager_membership.manager_id = manager.manager_id
```

I would expect two results like so:

```
+--------------------------------+-------------+------------+------------------------+------------+
| building_officer_membership_id | building_id | officer_id | manager_name           | manager_id |
+--------------------------------+-------------+------------+------------------------+------------+
|                              1 |           1 |          1 | Bill Lumbergh          | 1          |
|                              2 |           1 |          2 | Bob Page               | 2          |
+--------------------------------+-------------+------------+------------------------+------------+
```

Instead, I get this:

```
+--------------------------------+-------------+------------+------------------------+------------+
| building_officer_membership_id | building_id | officer_id | manager_name           | manager_id |
+--------------------------------+-------------+------------+------------------------+------------+
|                              1 |           1 |          1 | Bill Lumbergh,Bob Page | 1,2        |
+--------------------------------+-------------+------------+------------------------+------------+
```

Which is the combination of all the managers for the officers into one result.

If the tables are empty, and I make the SQL call, I get this, instead of an empty row:

```
+--------------------------------+-------------+------------+--------------+------------+
| building_officer_membership_id | building_id | officer_id | manager_name | manager_id |
+--------------------------------+-------------+------------+--------------+------------+
|                           NULL |        NULL |       NULL | NULL         | NULL       |
+--------------------------------+-------------+------------+--------------+------------+
```

I know that the bug is in the GROUP_CONCAT sections, since if I remove those,

```
select building_officer_membership.building_officer_membership_id,
    building_officer_membership.building_id,
    building_officer_membership.officer_id
    from building_officer_membership
    JOIN building on building.building_id = building_officer_membership.building_id
    JOIN officer on officer.officer_id = building_officer_membership.officer_id;
+--------------------------------+-------------+------------+
| building_officer_membership_id | building_id | officer_id |
+--------------------------------+-------------+------------+
|                              1 |           1 |          1 |
|                              2 |           1 |          2 |
+--------------------------------+-------------+------------+
```

I get the result I expect, just sans manger information.

So I am not too sure what is going on here. Are my joins being too greedy or something?

My MySQL version is 5.1.73.  For reasons beyond my control, I cannot upgrade to the latest version.  While in my webservice code that is using this SQL call, I can make a workaround to get around this that involves more SQL calls, I would rather do this in one swoop if possible.

Comment: you can remove tag to sql-server if it is of mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annnnd I figured it out. It was quite dumb.

select building_officer_membership.building_officer_membership_id, building_officer_membership.building_id, building_officer_membership.officer_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT manager.full_name) as manager_name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT manager.manager_id) AS manager_id from building_officer_membership JOIN building on building.building_id = building_officer_membership.building_id JOIN officer on officer.officer_id = building_officer_membership.officer_id JOIN officer_manager_membership on officer.officer_id = officer_manager_membership.officer_id JOIN manager ON officer_manager_membership.manager_id = officer.officer_id

**group by officer.officer_id**

TIL group_concat needs a group by to know how to organize the results, otherwise, it will return as little as possible.